# how to load jquery dialog in wordpress using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

how can i load a jquery dialog once the page is loaded? I mean I don't want to load it everytime i refresh the page.

I know it's something to do with cookies.

here is my dialog

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

    $j(document).ready(function(){

      $j('#west').dialog({show: 'slow', modal: true, height: 600, width: 850, title: 'Price Comparison Popup', resizable: false, draggable: false});        
      });        

    });
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with wp_enqueue_script. Also, you're wrapping a document ready function inside a document ready function. You only need one. ;-)

Comment: @Ronny: "I know it's something to do with cookies." NO you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your questions, but if you just want to add a jquery-ui script to your code, use something like:

```
//assuming you are working on a plugin
$plugin_url = plugins_url('myPlugin');
//register and enqueue the script
wp_register_script("jquery-dialog", $plugin_url . '/js/jquery.dialog.js', 'jquery');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-dialog');
```

That will include the script, and make sure it is loaded after Wordpress's version of jQuery.