# Cross-Origin warning on wp_enqueue_script for jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, cross-domain

The method for including scripts in my wordpress plugin is in another post: [how to load jquery dialog in wordpress using wp_enqueue_script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440410/how-to-load-jquery-dialog-in-wordpress-using-wp-enqueue-script)

I think this works fine for me, but I'm getting a weird error in the Firefox development tools console when I load my page, after enqueueing the jquery-ui stuff (js and css).  Here is my code:

```
wp_register_script( 'myplugin-jquery-ui', plugins_url("myplugin/js/jquery-ui.min.js" ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin-jquery-ui');
```

But when I load the page in Firefox, the console says:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

I can't find "fonts.gstatic.com" referenced ANYWHERE in ANY of my files, least of all the jquery-ui.min.js file.  Can you please help me understand a) why/how I'm getting this error, and b) if it's something I should just ignore?

And if I only need it for the dialog plugin, should I do be doing this differently?

Comment: I am getting the same problem in my jquery bootstrap debugging using FF.  Not sure if this is related, but I recently fixing a problem with my gitk not working and fixing it by updating my Adobe Unit Types.osax from Photoshop 3.

Comment: i have the same problem loading kml files in wordpress. any fix on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug by Google. It's not serving the header correctly sometimes for reasons only they know. A bullet-proof way to prevent this shame is get the font files and serve them yourself.

You can verify the received headers when the woff is served and you will se how they are not sending the header when the browser fails to load the font. If you can't believe your browser, check with a network sniffer tool like Wireshark.